# how to understand scope in go closure

Tags: go, closures

Does anybody know why the case1 output the same result, but the case2 output the sequential result?
I know the reason why case1 output the same value is that the closure of each function in functions slice access to the same scope.

But why after adding i:=i in each loop can case2 output the sequential result?
Does after redefining i in eachloop, a new scope is generated?
like let in javascript?

**case1**

```
func main() {
    funcs := []func() {}

    for i:=0;i<10;i++{
        funcs = append(funcs, func() {
            fmt.Println(i)
        })
    }

    for i:=0;i<10;i++{
        funcs[i]()
    }
}
```

**output**

```
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

**case2**

```
func main() {
    funcs := []func() {}

    for i:=0;i<10;i++{
        i := i
        funcs = append(funcs, func() {
            fmt.Println(i)
        })
    }

    for i:=0;i<10;i++{
        funcs[i]()
    }
}
```

**output**

```sh
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: *Scope* is related, but is the wrong term to use here. An `i := i` is a *short declaration* that creates a new `i`, so yes, this is a bit like `let` in Javascript. The *scope*, however, is there regardless of whether there's an inner declaration. The later reference to `i` uses the innermost scope `i` available. Without the short declaration, that's the outer `i`; with it, that's the inner `i`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/52980172/13860

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Captured Closure (for Loop Variable) in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692844/captured-closure-for-loop-variable-in-go)

Comment: Thanks you so much for your info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a scope issue but rather an issue with how the compiler decides if your variable `i` is captured by reference or by value. This is not always obvious. For loops in go reuse the iteration variable in this case the `i`. In **case1** the variable `i` is captured as a reference as the compiler sees it as being changed after the capture has taken place. In **case2** the inner variable `i` is created before the capture, captured and released thus the compiler sees it as unchanging and captures it by value. The result is when the functions are run in **case1** the results are all the final value as that is what the variable `i` ended up as and each function only holds a reference to that particular `i`. In **case2** each capture was passed a "copy" of `i` at the time of creation thus they show the values you expect.